# Cscope result handling with Quickfix window

Tags: vim, cscope

I am using cscope with quickfix support to display the result by setting `set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-` ~/.vimrc file

I can move between results with `:cnext` and `:cprevious` commands

What I want is to display the result in quickfix window first and do a preview before jumping to the file.

I tried using `set switchbuf+=usetab,newtab` but that gives a different result and not helping.

Is there a plugin or command available to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it by closing the buffer it opens (1st result) and then opening the results in a quickfix window by calling `:cwindow`.

Here's what my key remap looks like:

```
nnoremap <leader>s yiw:cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>:bd<CR>:cwindow<CR>/<C-R>0<CR>
```

Explanation:

- `yiw`- Yank the word under cursor for highlighting later
- `:cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>`- Standard cscope command to find a symbol
- `:bd<CR>`- Delete the buffer, so this closes the first search result
- `:cwindow<CR>`- Open search results in a new quickfix window
- `/<C-R>0<CR>`- Search for the symbol, so I get the symbol I looked up for highlighted in quickfix window and I can move within quickfix window using `n` and `N`.

I ended up writing a small plugin for this. You can check it out here - https://github.com/ronakg/quickr-cscope.vim

Comment: Good! I just removed the :bd part because if I am using it with NERDTree, then the currently buffer is closed and it mess up with the windows.